# Delete after insert inside transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I have inherited a nightmarish WTF sproc that inserts 300k rows into a table of outbound marketing emails.  We want to not queue messages to email addresses that are bouncing.  We have a separate table of bouncing emails.

The right way to do this is to modify the sproc to not insert rows for bouncing email.

Nobody wants to touch the nightmarish clusterfuck that is this particular sproc.  We are considering adding a delete command to the sproc thusly.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    --400+ lines of nightmarish WTF T-SQL, string and XML replacement nonsense goes here--
    DELETE FROM EmailQueueItems 
WHERE ToAddress IN 
    (SELECT EmailStatuses.Email FROM EmailStatuses 
        INNER JOIN EmailEventTypes on EmailEventTypes.EmailEventTypeId = EmailStatuses.EmailEventTypeId
        WHERE  EmailEventTypes.CanSendMarketing = 0)
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

so.... will this work? Can I delete inserts from a table before the transaction commits?

Comment: If the question can be boiled down to: can you insert and delete same records within a transaction, then the answer is yes.

Comment: Yeah, but if I asked it simply people might have said "yes, but make your code better so it doesn't have to."

Comment: This can be answered simply by trying it.

Comment: OK.  Sounds great.  Can you stay up all night babysitting the process to see if it dies because of this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can insert records, and delete same, to a table within the transaction.

Try this sample for proof of concept:

```
declare @foo table (id int)
begin tran

    insert into @foo 
        values (1),(2),(3)

    delete @foo where id = 2

    select * from @foo --will result in 2 rows: 1 and 3

commit tran
```

Comment: Is there any implications to doing this on a big insert (300k inserts) and then 50k deletes?

Comment: It will take longer and blocking may occur

Answer (score 0):

I think tackling the insert and doing it correctly to insert only the records you want is a better choice than inserting and then deleting. There should be a significant perfomance differnece between inserting 250,000 records and inserting 300,000 and then deleting 50,000. You are processing an extra 100,000 records you don't need to process. Bite the bullet and fix the process properly.

Comment: Absolutely "don't do this" is the right answer.  The problem is the 400+ lines of dynamic T-SQL plus XML parsing plus string concatenated parameter switches plus other untold horrors that fixing the sproc entails.  Our plan is to throw the sproc AND the even worse app that calls it away and rewrite the whole mess.  Next month.  For now, the cheesy hack will have to do.